# merge in jpa many-to-many with extra column in join table

Tags: java, jpa, merge, many-to-many, eclipselink

I have a many-to-many relationship with three tables and entities adn the join table contains additional column. On both sides of the relationship I have set cascadeType.All 
When I add new objects to owner side the merge method works fine but when I remove a child object from the owner and merge it, the corresponding **rows in the join table will not be removed and I will have duplicate rows in there.**

owner entity

```
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "definitionType")
    private List<DefinitionProperty> definitionProperties = new ArrayList<DefinitionProperty>();
```

---

```
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "property")  
    private List<DefinitionProperty> definitionProperties= new ArrayList<DefinitionProperty>();
```

---

mapping entity

```
    @Id
    @JoinColumn(name = "dtid", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private DefinitionType definitionType;

    @Id
    @JoinColumn(name = "prid", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Property property;
```

I am not calling remove method of my entity manager at all and I am expecting the cascading to remove the unwanted rows automatically. Is that possible? what should I do to in order to remove those rows?
I can add my code here if it help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just needed orphanRemoval=true on the owner side.